# Unknown projection of GRIB file

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, rasterio, grib

I have issues extracting geometrical shaped data from a GRIB raster of soil moisture. The file is for example `https://gimms.gsfc.nasa.gov/SMOS/jbolten/FAS/L03/20100113_20100115.as1.grib`

Using either GDAL or Rasterio I can read the file and display it here.
[image]

Its CRS is `CRS({'proj': 'stere', 'lat_0': 90, 'lat_ts': 60, 'lon_0': 1, 'k': 1, 'x_0': 0, 'y_0': 0, 'a': 6371200, 'b': 6371200, 'units': 'm', 'no_defs': True})`

or with `gdalinfo` it reads

```
Driver: GRIB/GRIdded Binary (.grb, .grb2)
Files: 20141227_20141229.as1.grib
Size is 1440, 600
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["Sphere",6371200,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",60],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",1],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0]]
Origin = (662126.628862303332426,59159218.394239947199821)
Pixel Size = (25000.000000000000000,-25000.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  662126.629,59159218.394) (179d38'28.48"W, 67d16'31.51"S)
Lower Left  (  662126.629,44159218.394) (179d51'32.52"W, 59d52' 0.26"S)
Upper Right (36662126.629,59159218.394) (149d12'45.70"E, 70d36'45.13"S)
Lower Right (36662126.629,44159218.394) (141d17'58.79"E, 66d35'39.62"S)
Center      (18662126.629,51659218.394) (161d 8'15.06"E, 65d34'25.05"S)
Band 1 Block=1440x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = 0[-] SFC (Ground or water surface)
  NoData Value=9999
  Metadata:
    GRIB_COMMENT=undefined [-]
    GRIB_ELEMENT=var255
    GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS=86400 sec
    GRIB_REF_TIME=  1419638400 sec UTC
    GRIB_SHORT_NAME=0-SFC
    GRIB_UNIT=[-]
    GRIB_VALID_TIME=  1419724800 sec UTC
```

The issue occurs if I want to extract a region from the raster, using a predefined shape. 
[image]

Using `rasterio.warp.transform_geom` with source CRS EPSG:4326 and dest CRS of the GRIB file above, I end up having a huge shape and of course the new one does not intersect with the raster.
[image]

Could anyone show me how to do it right with this GRIB format? I have done such operation without any problem on netcdf, hdf, and geotiff files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That data is definitely not in polar stereographic, that CRS has been misapplied - I had a stab in the dark, and assigned it longitude/latitude and bounded at 60S and 90N (using R):

```
library(raster)
r <- raster("~/20100113_20100115.as1.grib")
#plot(r) ## wrong
#plot(extent(r), add = T)

extent(r) <- extent(-180, 180, -60, 90)
projection(r) <- "+init=epsg:4326"
plot(r)
maps::map(add = T)
```

At the command line you can use `gdal_translate` arguments `[-a_srs srs_def] [-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry]` to do the same, but - I would certainly want to know *why* this has occurred. You don't want to have to fix stuff like this ad hoc downstream.

Grib is a domain-specific format, and to have one *created* like this arbitrarily is weird to me -  and it being done wrong is really going to cause problems for someone.

[image]

Comment: WYSIWYG turns out to be applied here. I am going to email the product admin if they ever want to support the users better.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking there was a chance it might be GDAL for some reason loading the GRIB definition incorrectly, but I just opened it with NDFD DEGRIB and it's still showing that incorrect projection.  Please contact the data admin and let them know about this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct answer very helpful, but I needed it in Python instead of R. So I've attached my code that (I believe) does the same thing as what @Thomas posted but in Python. The only Python library it uses is GDAL.

```
translate_options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format='GTiff', outputSRS='EPSG: 4326', outputBounds=[-179, 90, 180, -60])
translate_output = gdal.Translate(destName=output_filename, srcDS=src_filename, options=translate_options)
```

Comment: Hi Glayne.. was facing the same issue and finally found something in Web. Trying to use your code in Python but it is not working. Is there anything i am missing?