# GeoTIFF creation using gdal_translate fails to produce expected result

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

I am converting weather radar data (grib2) to raster tiles for Mapbox. The resulting tiles are mis-aligned from the original grib2 data and I am not sure why. I have a 4-step process using GDAL in the command line to convert the grib2 to raster tiles, which I will go into great detail below. The weather data provider provides an online viewer for their data, so I was able to make an example by matching the zoom and capturing the difference :

[image]

I am providing the grib2 file for anyone that needs it [on Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10V8mcsmiE1ldOQECoiglGA-gIcjQrbFF/view?usp=sharing)

Edit :  This is the  [colorization file needed for testing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14v1s2fvWKxCg_KlJ0pI8SHxRcCNB098K/view?usp=sharing)

**Here is my process to convert this data to tiles**, and I suspect the problem is with gdalwarp somehow, but I am not sure. EDIT - Based on comments,  It now seems gdal_translate is the likely culprit.

1. Use *gdal_translate* to convert the grib2 file to a GeoTiff

`gdal_translate -b 1 MRMS_ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude_00.50_20211212-172838.grib2 Output.tif`

2. Use *gdalwarp* to reproject the Output.tif to 3857 for Mapbox.

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 Output.tif Output-projected.tif`

3. I use *gdaldem* to colorize the file (color is different, this is intentional).

`gdaldem color-relief -alpha Output-projected.tif colorization_file.txt Output-colorized.tif`

4. Last, I use *gdal2tiles* to tile the image for Mapbox.

`python gdal2tiles.py --profile=mercator --processes=8 -x --zoom=0-13 Output-colorized.tif outputDir`

I have ran gdalinfo on the output from each step in the process so that anyone may see in detail :

- [gdalinfo for original GRIB2 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MkHgnU6RUjb3mA-ffcgpA09TSRT-70eb/view?usp=sharing)
- [gdalinfo for Output.tif (step 1)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DOODsYFCkfUitBlrT2NsvAycBdqqtBCY/view?usp=sharing)
- [gdalinfo for Output-projected.tif (step 2)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TqnPvFc6iPVIcIJ3X_j3hai0dexL-Pb8/view?usp=sharing)
- [gdalinfo for Output-colorized.tif (step 3)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bvRiBJ1K49QbCyDDl_IQ74bxVknJytnm/view?usp=sharing)

As a bonus, if anyone wanted to visually check this exact data location it is located in Florida at -81.42, 28.85. This is in case someone wants to check the data using their own software.

*Edit :  For clarity, I am using GDAL 3.4.0, released 2021/11/04*

With all of the information above, I can only guess at what I am doing wrong. After hours of fiddling with the script I am still pretty clueless. I have an idea that it has to do with gdalwarp because this is the initial point where I had attempted to change the projection. If anyone needs more information, I will gladly edit this post to include it.

Comment: Which projection is used for the source data (grib2 file ?). Is `output.tif` resulting from gdal_translate correctly projected ? Also, you may have a look on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299954/unknown-projection-of-grib-file

Comment: @simo I do not know the projection of the source file, but it might be because I don't know what I am looking at. I included a link to the gdalinfo for the source file. I see EPSG 9001, 9122, and 9122 listed. I am unsure which one is the actual projection, or if they all mean the same thing?

Comment: Try what happens if you edit the output from step 1 with `gdal_edit -mo AREA_OR_POINT=Point Output.tif --config GTIFF_POINT_GEO_IGNORE YES`  and then repeat the next steps.

Comment: Please try that edit. I suspect that the issue comes from setting the anchor point either into the centre of a pixel or into the top left corner of the pixel.

Comment: @user30184 I had just tried that edit, it does move the data some, but it is now further north than it should be, and still not enough to the west. It is still within the same general area though. (It seems it was more accurate without this gdal_edit script)

Comment: Grib2 format seems to be complicated. I would like to see from the data what is the real georeference of the data instead of to rely on the map on the web site. Lots of tools are listed in https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-best-software-or-code-to-analyze-grib-grb-data.

Comment: @user30184 The map on their website is correct, it matches the data from the NOAA Weather-Climate toolkit (one is a web viewer and the other is multi-platform software). I am positive my projection is wrong.

Comment: Write mail to gdal-dev mailing list, include link to test data, and explain how to get the correct location with the reference software. Your workflow is OK, perhaps GDAL makes an error when it interprets the grib file and finds `GEOGCRS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file"`. Check `output.tif` with QGIS to make sure that it is incorrectly placed already at that phase.

Comment: @user30184 I will do that. I do think GDAL should pick this up automatically. However I think you are on the right track about the anchor point. Are there other possibilities? My projection is very close. Someone that also helped me with this problem in an email told me ... "It is likely a misunderstanding on the pixel origin.  I forget exactly which it is, but moving 0.5 pixel width up and down appears to align your example up." -- Does that give any clue?

Comment: The AREA_OR_POINT=Point edit leads to half a pixel shift but you told that the result was not satisfactory.

Comment: @user30184 Okay, that makes sense. So you and the other person both had the same idea and it was not the problem. This has become more complex than I thought it would be. I appreciate your assistance thus far.

Comment: @user30184 This may be unrelated, and I am not sure if it's any clue or not - but I am using gdal2tiles in this script - and it says in the source code " Pixel and tile coordinates are in TMS notation (origin [0,0] in bottom-left)." When I am converting the grib2 to geoTIF using gdal_translate, is there something I should do because of this?

Comment: colorization_file.txt ` is missing?

Comment: @FaridCheraghi Thank you for noticing, I have edited the question with the data. You may also get it here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/14v1s2fvWKxCg_KlJ0pI8SHxRcCNB098K/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please limit the issue to one of the resulting files that first shows the error. You can use QGIS to compare to your data to a background map and find out which tool invocation is the cause. Otherwise it is too much guesswork what it might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, data stored in a raster format is not meant to be visualized at a scale where the pixels are visible. I therefore do not consider this problem as a geometric accuracy issue but as a precision issue.

Because of the reprojection, your squares pixels in the original coordinate system will become rectangles in the Mercator projection ("vertically" stretched). The "vertical" size of your pixels will not be constant because it depends on the latitude, therefore you cannot precisely reproject your dataset with pixels of constant size. As far as I know, Mapbox requires sqaure pixels, so no matter what tool you use, the information content will be modified. Now, let's see how we can minimize the distortions of the information.

When the size of the pixel changes, you need to assign a new value to the projected pixels. As mentioned in the previous post, you could replace the "nearest neighbor" (default) algorythm with an algorithm that combines the values of the neighbours. I recommend **-r bilinear** or (for a smoother result) **-r cubic**. Note that you seem to have values of -999 that are in fact no data, so in order to avoid problems around the boundaries, define those values as nodata (using gdal_edit.py).

You can minimize the shift by forcing the pixel size based on the X-width of your pixels, using the option **-tr 1111 1111** (to keep square pixels). This will not solve vertical alignment issues, but it will be ok horizontally. Note that if you work only on a small specific area, you can select a compromise between your X and Y values on this area.

Another workaround is to artificially increase the resolution of your raster, so that you can rebuild the "rectangles" to better match their footprint in the new projection (then using again the nearest neighbor resampling will preserve the original values of the raster). The drawback is that it will increase the size of your dataset : if you take 111 m for the size of your pixels, you multiply the (uncompressed) size of your raster by 100.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the grib2 file to do the process step-by-step and identify in which point does this error occur. In a first glance, I also thought it might be an issue in the first step (transforming grib2 to tif), but I then found that the apparent shift happens in the GDAL Warp step and is simply due to a nearest neighbor interpolation.

#### First step:

Such as the author, I also used the [snippet available in my website](https://www.luisalucchese.com/post/how-to-read-grib2-raster-python/) for saving a grib2 file to into Python.

(I would appreciate if the question author could edit the question and add that he has been trying to use this script for step #1 as well, thanks!)

To be exact, this is the script:

```
from osgeo import gdal
arq1 = gdal.Open (‘gribfile.grib2’)
GT_entrada = arq1.GetGeoTransform()
print(GT_entrada)
save_arq = gdal.Translate('tif_file.tif’,arq1)
```

I then opened both the grib2 and the tif files in QGIS. Same pixel size, same projection, same extent, same everything. I do not think this is where the shift happens.

#### Second step:

I didn’t do the GDAL Warp processing on CLI, I chose to use the Warp (Reproject) tool on QGIS, which uses the same algorithms. If you fill only the fields of the input raster and the output projection, it does the same calculation as shown in the question. The default interpolation type is Nearest Neighbour (or Neighbor), which will “copy” the value of the closest pixel on the original raster to the pixel on the new one. Because other values, such as the pixel size, and the extent, were not provided to the algorithm, the pixel size changed in this operation, as well as the number of pixels in each direction. This change off-centered the locations of pixels, in respect to the original raster. Combining this change with the interpolation used, it may appear, in first sight, that the pixels have “shifted”. I have another example of this “occurrence” [on my blog](https://www.luisalucchese.com/post/qgis-tools-warp-reproject-clip-raster-by-extent-clip-raster-by-mask-layer/). If I force the extent to change and the pixel size to stay the same, while performing Nearest Neighbor, I see a shift in the pixels.
To make sure it was that, I also did the same operation (GDAL Warp), but with bilinear interpolation. In the resulting raster, an outer region filled with the interpolated values became visible. This reinforces the other findings.

#### I did not go further into the steps because I genuinely think that solving this will solve the whole issue.

I could not think of a complete solution, but I have some ideas of workarounds (but I am not sure these will work for your case and application, please use your discretion when applying them).

#### Suggested workarounds:

- Using an interpolation other than Nearest Neighbor. Look into interpolation options and choose a different one.
- Choose a fixed pixel size when interpolating with GDAL Warp. You can choose this based on the location you mainly want the map to be as correct as possible.
- Choose a different output projection or use the original projection.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not sure of the source GRIB projection format, I will give you the advice to try specifying the projection for source file when using `gdalwarp`.

`gdalwarp  -s_srs EPSG:9001 -t_srs EPSG:3857 Output.tif Output-projected.tif`

OR

`gdalwarp  -s_srs EPSG:9122 -t_srs EPSG:3857 Output.tif Output-projected.tif`

See projection extent validity on https://epsg.io/ website :

- https://epsg.io/9001
- https://epsg.io/9122 (does not seem to fit the location you are working on)

Comment: Unfortunately, these do not work - the output projection is exactly the same as my problem example image.

Comment: from where did you get your GRIB files ?

Comment: The GRIB2 files come from this directory with live data : https://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/2D/MergedReflectivityAtLowestAltitude/ ... it is part of the MRMS (Multi-Radar-Multi-Sensor) project at https://www.nssl.noaa.gov/projects/mrms/ . The second link has information but I see nothing about projection.

Comment: I guess gdal should anyway understand .... Have you tried to convert the grib file from another converter such as https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/grib-to-geotiff or directly read GRIB file in a GIS ?

Comment: Yes, I have used another program (plus their online viewer) and verified that my reprojection is wrong. I have not tried your link yet. I will try that as well just for more test data.

Comment: In the WKT that gdalinfo shows EPSG:9001 means metre https://epsg.org/unit_9001/metre.html and EPSG:9122 means degree. They are codes for units, not for coordinate reference system so using them as -s_srs is wrong.